# Wave-functions in strong gravitational fields?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, gravity, wavefunction

When I was introduced to quantum mechanics at university, a wave function was described as a function $\Psi: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, that is space + time. General relativity, meanwhile, is modeled as a 4-manifold.

According to Frederic Schuller's lecture series on Youtube, when fitting the idea of the wave function to a manifold, it should more correctly be implemented as a section of the $\mathbb{C}$-bundle over the manifold, the main difference being that in the "classical" view (if you will excuse the label), $\Psi$ maps $\mathbb{R}^4$ to the same copy of $\mathbb{C}$, whereas in the manifold implementation, each point in space-time maps into a 'private' copy of $\mathbb{C}$. In weak gravity, this doesn't give rise to measurable effects - the bundle is locally trivial, and when gravity is weak, the two methods approach each other over large volumes of space-time.

But what happens in a (very) strong gravity field?

---

EDIT: I was asked to provide a link to the lecture, and that puts me on the spot; the problem being that professor Schuller has published several series with quite a number of indicidual lectures in each, and I don't remember which lecture. I think it was in "Lectures on Geometrical Anatomy of Theoretical Physics":

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic

However, it may be to the benefit of the reader; his lecturing style is very clear and captivating - I think anybody who watches his lectures will want to watch them all. There's another series called "Lectures on Quantum Theory":

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbqA9Xn_iM0&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxQVx5jRjbfRGEzWY_upS5K6

One thing to note: for some reason his name is spelled as Fredric Schuller on Youtube, but Frederic Schuller elsewhere. One version is presumably a spelling mistake.

Comment: Link to lecture? Minute?

Comment: Sorry, I've included a link now, see edit.

Comment: In case you do not know, it is highly debated and totally open how to fundamentally describe quantum gravity (i.e. that theory that is supposed to merge gravity and quantum mechanics).

Comment: @Luke If I read the question correctly, it is about quantum mechanics in a curved background (a semi-classical theory), not about quantum gravity.

Comment: @Sebastian: that is correct - my question is not about quantum gravity